# Ensure first and last characters of text box are numbers c#

Tags: c#, regex, forms, character, windows-forms-designer

Im currently creating a windows form that must only allow a password through when it matches certain criteria. Im close to finishing however im a bit stuck with one element. "the first and last characters of the password HAVE to be numbers".

looking at my current code how would i go about this because i have ZERO idea. so baby steps and patience would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace password_test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        bool Finished = false;


        private bool TestPassword(string passwordText, int minimumLength =     5, int maximumLength = 12, int minimumNumbers = 1, int minimumLetters = 1)
    {


        int letters = 0;
        int digits = 0;
        int minLetters = 0;


        if (passwordText.Length < minimumLength)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must have at least " + minimumLength + " characters in your password.");
            return false;
        }

        if (passwordText.Length > maximumLength)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must have no more than " + maximumLength + " characters in your password.");
            return false;
        }

        foreach (var ch in passwordText)
        {
            if (char.IsLetter(ch)) letters++; 
            if (char.IsDigit(ch)) digits++; 

            if (ch > 96 && ch < 123)
            {
                minLetters++;
            }
        }


        if (digits < minimumNumbers)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must have at least " + minimumNumbers + " numbers in your password.");
            return false;
        }

        if (minLetters < minimumLetters)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must have at least " + minimumLetters + " letter in your password");
            return false;
        }
        Finished = true;
        return true;


    }


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void butConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {





        if (txtPassword.Text == txtRetypePassword.Text)
        {
                bool temp = TestPassword(txtPassword.Text, 10, 100, 1, 1);


            if (Finished == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Password Accepted");
                Application.Exit();
                //this.Hide();
                //Form2 f2 = new Form2();
                //f2.ShowDialog();

            }
        }


        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please ensure the passwords you have typed match");
            return;
        }


    }

    private void txtPassword_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    private void txtRetypePassword_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }




}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before `Finished = true;` you can simply do your check:

```
if (!char.IsDigit(passwordText[0]) || !char.IsDigit(passwordText[passwordText.Length - 1])) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("The first and last characters of the password  have to be numbers");
    return false;   
}
Finished = true;
```

You should also enforce a minimum length in your method.

Comment: No problem. You can mark the answer as correct so others looking at the question know the answer helped.

Comment: How would i reverse this so the first and last characters are not numbers?

Comment: The `!` is the not operator. If you remove that from before 'char' then you would get the error message if the first or last character is a digit.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use Regex  [Test Pattern](https://regex101.com)

```
  //  ^\d = start with digit  
  //  \d$ end with digit
  //  .{3,10}  including start and ending, min 5 max 12 
  if (!Regex.IsMatch(str, @"\d.{3,10}\d$")
  {
       // Invalid 
  }
```

Use \D to reverse.